# Display data in the JasperReports's table view using Spring mvc

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jasper-reports

I'm not able to display data in *JasperReports's* table, view getting empty.

But in *iReport* for same jrxml file I am able to display

The code in Spring Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "displayTradeList")
public ModelAndView displayTradeListHtml(ModelAndView modelAndView) {
    tradeList = service.getTradeList();

    JRDataSource JRdataSource = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(tradeList);

    Map<String, Object> parameterMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    parameterMap.put("datasource", JRdataSource);

    //xlsReport bean has ben declared in the jasper-views.xml file
    modelAndView = new ModelAndView("htmlReport", parameterMap);

    return modelAndView;
}  please find below jrxml file:http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/826043/display-data-jasperreportss-table-view
```

Comment: can you provide your jrxml file content?

Comment: Thanks for repaly Vishal .

Comment: i am not able to post .jrxml file.File size is more .please tel me how to post the file

Comment: Hi..as stackoverflow.com doesn't provide to upload file, you can do one thing. Upload your file to Google Drive and then give access (anybody with link can see) to that file. And after that provide URL in your POST. I always do this ;)

Comment: Hi Vishal thanks for replay i have another question on springmvc with jasper is  ;;i have designed jrxml in ireport created inputcontrol in jasperreportserver to achived filter in Jasperreportserver.same functionality i need to achieve in springmvc with jsp/html using tomcatserver. please let me know this can be achieved ? .currently i have done same using ireport using jasperreportserver .please please respond any one this is urgent

Comment: hi Vishal Zanzrukia plese find jrxml file:http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/826043/display-data-jasperreportss-table-view.

Comment: can you make sure that you are using exact same names of fields in your bean (which you are passing in DataSource as a list) as your jrxml field names?

Comment: Yes .Dao implementation return list

Comment: ArrayList<TradeDetails> getTradeList() 
 {
  RowMapper<TradeDetails> mapper = new RowMapper<TradeDetails>() 
  {
    public TradeDetails mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException 
    {
     TradeDetails td = new TradeDetails();
     
     td.setOwner(rs.getString(1));
     td.setDeskid(rs.getString(2));
     
     td.setErrorcode(rs.getString(3));
      td.setCountvalue(rs.getString(4));
     return td;
    }
  };
   
  ArrayList<TradeDetails> tradeList= (ArrayList<TradeDetails>) simpleJdbcTemplate.query(TRADE_LIST, mapper);
  return tradeList;
 }

Comment: Currnently i am using Database JDBC conntection in ireport Datasource.